# How to implement the function thread safe

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-safety

I am calling a function(that returns string) from macro . Multiple threads can use this macro in the system.

### E.g :

```
#define LOG(app,str) printf("App =%d\n, Ouptut String = %s\n",app, 
foo str );


char* foo(const char *fmt, ...) {
static char logmsg[200]; //Maximum log Msg String length
va_list args;
va_start(args, fmt);
vsprintf(logmsg,fmt, args);
va_end(args);
return logmsg;
}



LOG Macro Usage : LOG(15,("Msg=%s\n",strvariable));
```

Now in my case function `foo()` is not thread safe. Any way how to make this macro/func as thread safe without using mutex locks????

Comment: mutex? why are you doing this yourself? use something like boost::log.

Comment: the fact that there is a macro involved is rather irrelevant. The threads dont even see the macro because it gets expanded by the preprocessor way before you start a thread

Comment: why using that vararg-crap in C++?

Comment: What will `foo str` do? seems syntactically invalid.

Comment: C or C++? The posted code is pure C.

Comment: @TheTechel The code is tagged C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to protect an internal buffer. Obviously you can't apply a mutex or atomic lock in the function because that buffer is used outside the function.

Ignoring the obvious flaw in the design and implementation (fixed length buffer with no protection, etc...) there is one way to protect the buffer.

That is to make it thread_local:

```
char* foo(const char *fmt, ...) {

  // thread_local
  thread_local static char logmsg[200]; //Maximum log Msg String length

  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  std::vsprintf(logmsg,fmt, args);
  va_end(args);
  return logmsg;
}
```

As long as you don't marshal the returned pointer between threads, you're good.

Note that thread_local is a c++11 feature, and the apple compiler still doesn't implement it when compiling for iOS. The workaround for that nonsense is `boost::thread_specific_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's pure C answer that produces a string that's fully usable by any thread, doesn't rely on a static buffer that will be overwritten by the next use, and doesn't risk a buffer overrun:

```
char *foo( const char *fmt, ... )
{
    // start with what's likely enough memory
    char local_buffer[ 128 ];

    va_list args;
    va_start( args, fmt );

    int bytes_needed = vsnprintf( local_buffer, sizeof( local_buffer ), fmt, args );

    va_end( args );

    // if the string fit, duplicate the string dynamically and return
    if ( bytes_needed < sizeof( local_buffer )
    {
        return( strdup( local_buffer );
    }

    // didn't fit, but we do know how long it needs to be
    char *buffer = malloc( bytes_needed + 1 );
    if ( !buffer )
    {
        return( NULL );
    }

    // can't safely reuse args
    va_list args2;
    va_start( args2, fmt );

    vsnprintf( buffer, bytes_needed, fmt, args2 );

    va_end( args2 );

    return( buffer );
}
```

Comment: You can't safely reuse `args` without intervening calls to `va_end()` and a new `va_start()`.  You don't need two variables.  What you can't do is call `va_start()`, then call `vsnprintf()` the first time, then call it a second time without the `va_end()` and another `va_start()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks.  I can never remember particulars like that, so I tend to err on the side of caution.  I'd rather write code that I *know* is safe than code that I *think* should be safe.